# Don't focus on evince, when compiling pdf from org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-export, pdf, focus

I'm using Evince as my Pdf-Viewer (In a split-screen-setup) whenever i write something in org-mode and compile it as a pdf. To achieve this, i've added

```
(add-to-list 'org-file-apps '("pdf" . "evince %s"))
```

to my .emacs and it simply works. However, when i compile and open as a pdf from org-mode, Emacs loses focus onto Evince.

The desired behavior would be for Emacs to obtain focus and run Evince in the background so that i wouldn't have to switch back to Emacs, whenever i compile as a pdf

Comment: I think this is more a function of your window manager settings than emacs.

Comment: Yes, that might be the case. However, when i compile LaTeX directly from a .tex-file with AucTeX and Evince it works as desired.